# Problems with @Autowire annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Class A, I'm auto-wiring Class B which has @Service annotation. In my Class B I'm auto-wiring class C and using reference to that class inside @Transactional method in class B.

And it appears that Auto-Wiring didn't do anything because I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Example of Class A :

```
@Controller
public Class controller{
   @Autowired
   private MyService myservice;
}
```

Class B

```
@Service
public Class serviceImpl{
   @Autowired
   private DAOInterface dao;
   //nullpointer

   @Transactional
   public String getItem(){
    return dao.getItem(2);
   }

}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Can you post your context.xml (or equivalent) contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `@Autowired` annotation to do your Spring wiring for you, you need to register the proper `BeanPostProcessor`'s to assist.  You can have Spring do this for you by including the following element in your Spring configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Take a look at [Section 3.9 in the Spring 3.0 Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) for more information on this.

Also, since it appears that you are using the stereotype annotations (`@Component`, `@Service`, `@Controller`), you may be trying to forego Spring XML wiring (or reducing it).  You will need to make sure that you are including the component-scan element in your Spring XML.

NOTE:  If you are including `component-scan`, then you should not need to use the `annotation-config` element.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name"/>
```

Take a look at [Section 3.10 in the Spring 3.0 Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) for more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're DAO is configured in some way...whether it be with an annotation (@Service, @Component, @Repository), in the xml configuration, or through some other means.

If this doesn't help, we will need more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public Class serviceImpl implements MyService {
   @Autowired
   private DAOInterface dao;
   //nullpointer

   @Transactional
   public String getItem(){
    return dao.getItem(2);
   }

}
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

`<context:annotation-config/>`

Comment: Please explain what you are doing instead of just posting the answer. Documentation would be great!